How do aeroplane wings work?
I wonder why this question has not been posed on this forum.
Is it such a dumb question that nobody needs to ask because the answer is obvious?
A search on the internet for "How do wings work" yields millions of hits, each one bafflingly different from the next.
I would have thought that any answer would include a working example, a simple back-of-the-envelope set of calculations that show that applying real life numbers to the offered theory would show how it works. After all, that's how most science works. You have an idea, you put numbers to it and then see if it works out in practice.

That's how Kepler demonstrated his theory of planetary orbits.
That's how Boyle demonstrated the relationship between the pressure and volume of a gas.
That's how modern physicists used Einstein's theory to explain the variation in the orbit of Mercury.
Whether or not Galileo actually used different sized canon balls to
demonstrate his theory is open to debate.
That's how the Michelson-Morley experiment disproved the theory of
Ether

The list goes on and on.
The scientific process follows a well-worn path:

A theory is developed to explain a physical phenomenon
The theory is developed into a mathematical equation
Numbers are applied to the theory,
Experimentation demonstrates the validity of the theory.

Further experimentation maybe supports the theory, disproves the theory or demonstrates the limitations of the applicability (Newton remained unchallenged until modern physics started to investigate domains beyond human experience, of the very fast, the very heavy or the very tiny.)
Amongst the myriads of explanations for how wings work there appear to be two major competing theories: one invoking the Bernoulli principle to explain the pressure variations around the wing which generate the force and one relying on the momentum change of the disturbed air to account for the aerodynamic force, the vertical component of which balances the weight of the aircraft.
In my search for an answer, I have been unable to find any even "back-of-the-envelope" calculations, using the mathematical equations derived from the theory, real-life numbers and experimental data to support any of these theories.
Is there any paper, journal of textbook which offers a theory and supports it with worked example using real-life data?
For example, one which could demonstrate how a 1-tonne Cessna 172 remains in straight and level flight at 5,000 ft above the ground at 100 kts?
(And I mean a theory that does not rely on a look-up table of Cl/Cd values)
[EDIT]
Since posting this question It has been pointed out that two similar questions have already been posted:
How do wings generate lift? (12 answers)
How complete is our understanding of lift? (9 answers)
Both of these posts generated much discussion but contained no worked examples to support the various claims.
As noted in my question, Physics is an experimental science where the validity of a theory is supported by experimental evidence that real-world numbers applied to the theory correspond to the experimental results.
My question, whilst on the same subject, presents a specific request for a worked example.

To add something to the already given answer: Bernoulli and downward push of air are not competing explanations, they both stem from the 2nd and 3rd Newton principle aka momentum conservation, they are two sides of the same coin.

Why the downvotes? The question is valid and well argumented. The current answer is very interesting.

I submitted and edited version for review 6 days ago. What's the status please?

I think your fundamental premise is unfortunately false.
Kepler's laws were purely empirical.  He had no actual theoretical basis for them.  He used a tremendous amount of data (thanks to Tycho Brahe) and essentially observed the trends.  He just happened to be correct.
Somewhat amusingly (at least to me), beyond Kepler's three laws that we celebrate today, Kepler believed in a fourth law that was absolutely not correct.  He was equally confident in the fourth law, but we virtually erase it from history because it wasn't correct.
There is no simple back of the envelope calculation for a modern physics based deviation in Mercury's orbit.
Many physical phenemona do not reduce down to an elementary algebraic equation.
Aerodynamics -- including the generation of lift -- is very well understood.  It has also been validated through experiment (many wind tunnel tests and flight tests) where the theory and experiment are in very close agreement.  In fact, we have several approaches to the development of the aerodynamic equations -- depending on the assumptions and simplifications we wish to make.
Engineers have a very good understanding of how these levels of theory compare and which are better / worse at predicting reality in different situations.
The issue at hand is that the fundamental theory of aerodynamics does not boil down to a simple equation with immediately obvious physical interpretation.
Everything in aerodynamics can be explained in terms of (and rigorously derived from):

Conservation of mass
Conservation of momentum
Conservation of energy
Gas equation of state
Some other gas relations like the dependence of viscosity on temperature

These five things are intuitive, observable, testable, etc.  There are multiple ways to get from these five things to aerodynamics....
Unfortunately, they are not simple algebraic equations.  Instead, they are a coupled system of nonlinear partial differential equations (1-3) (with some algebraic equations thrown in (4,5)).
The 'modern' way uses the least mathematical abstraction.  It is called CFD (computational fluid dynamics).  In CFD, we divide the domain of interest into a large number of tiny elements.  We initialize all of the elements to an initial guess (that is wrong).  We then solve the above equations on every element, applying appropriate boundary conditions.  This makes a small correction to the properties at every element.  We then do it again, and again, and again....
CFD is a very brute force approach with very little mathematical abstraction.  After millions and millions of calculations, if we're lucky, the properties in all of the elements stops changing (there is theory on how this should happen too).  We then say that the solution is converged.  We can then sum pressures and shear to get lift and drag, we can produce beautiful images of the flow, etc.  We have 'solved' the flow.
Although CFD is very powerful, it is not very satisfying in terms of intuition (which is what you're after).
There are other ways to attack aerodynamics (and the calculation of lift).  You mentioned Bernoulli's equation -- Bernoulli's equation is most frequently derived from the conservation of energy, but it also can be derived from the conservation of momentum.
Potential flow theory (which most pre-CFD low-speed aerodynamics theory was based on) is usually derived from the conservation of mass -- but can also be derived from the conservation of momentum.
Potential flow theory allows aerodynamic calculation with much less brute force than CFD -- but instead, it adopts a great deal of mathematical abstraction.  Complex variables (imaginary numbers), a potential function, sources, sinks, and vortices (mathematical singularities), superposition of elementary solutions, etc.
All of this can be rigorously derived from the fundamental equations -- and all of it has been validated through comparison to experiment.  And more than 100 years of successful application to the design of aircraft.  Engineers have deep understanding of their applicability and limits.
Unfortunately, although all of this is true, it does not mean that it can be explained in one or two sentences without heaps of math.
Any simple explanation of lift is wrong.
Any rigorous and correct explanation of lift is going to get messy.

+1 for Any simple explanation of lift is wrong. -- This should be engraved on the lintel of every flight school in the world.

"Unfortunately, although all of this is true, it does not mean that it can be explained in one or two sentences without heaps of math." I'm not deterred by heaps of maths or an explanation that takes more than a sentence or two. My problem is that I haven't found A N Y  explanation that uses real-world numbers on even a simplified model to explain the source of the 10,000 N required to support a 1-tonne light aircraft in level flight.

@BlastWave Perhaps you are looking in the wrong place.  I suggest you look in any undergraduate aerodynamics textbook.  I am also curious what your definition of "explanation" is.  What would satisfy you?  There are no analytical solutions for 3D lifting flow -- this means we must use numerical methods to solve any 3D lifting flow.  Here is a link to Bertin & Smith, check out Example 7.2 that starts on page 365.  https://www.airloads.net/Downloads/Textbooks/Aerodynamics-for-engineers-%20John%20J.Bertin.pdf

The end result of that example is Figure 7.32, which gives the lift coefficient vs. angle of attack for the given wing.  You can easily dimensionalize that lift coefficient at a wing area and flight condition (airspeed and altitude) of your choice to see the magnitude of force that is created.

Big issue with Bertin's book (Chapter 7). Air, a gas, is treated as incompressible. Physics basics say there are 3 states: solid, liquid, gas. Bertin claims only solid or fluid. He also seems to misunderstand the key differences between liquids and gases, established in 17th century! Liquids have weaker bonds than solids, and gases have none. This directly affects how they fill containers (gas expands, liquid doesn't). Basically, the book ignores key properties of gas.

A quantity of gas will fill a container of any volume. A quantity liquid will retain its volume irrespective of the volume of its container.

@BlastWave That is not at all what incompressible means in the aerodynamic sense.  Not even in the slightest.  When we say that an aerodynamics problem is incompressible, we are saying that the density is constant throughout the problem of interest.  It can be whatever it needs to be (expand to fill the container), but whatever that value is, it is going to be a constant for our system.

Further, aerodynamicists do not always treat air as incompressible -- instead, we recognize that in certain limited circumstances, we can treat air as incompressible.  This is not a property of air, but instead a property of the circumstances.

Take a bar of metal.  If  you throw it, you can likely treat it as a rigid body.  If you constrain one end and apply a moderate load, you can likely treat it as a linear elastic structure.  If you apply a heavy load, then it will deform in a nonlinear, plastic manner.  Rigid, elastic, or plastic is not an attribute of the bar.  It is an attribute of the circumstances and the bar.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Are you seriously suggesting that "incompressible" has a meaning in aerodynamics different to that in classical physics? Or that the density (mass per unit volume) of a quantity of gas (air) change other than by changing its volume? Is there nobody out there who doesn't see the paradox in that idea?

My 6th edition Bertin (vs. your 5th) expands on fluid as a continuum (section 1.2.2) but gets tangled. It claims a "continuous flux...through boundaries" while maintaining a "constant number of molecules." This is illogical. Continuous flux means uninterrupted flow, while a boundary implies limitation. This wouldn't work for gases: they expand to fill their container, and without a defined volume (no container), gas volume is meaningless
